# How can I refine my Python reverse image search to limit to a specific domain?

Tags: python-3.x, django, image, google-image-search

I'm using Python 3.8.  I have the following script for launching a Google reverse image search ...

```
    filePath = '/tmp/cat_and_dog.webp'
    searchUrl = 'http://www.google.hr/searchbyimage/upload'
    multipart = {'encoded_image': (filePath, open(filePath, 'rb')), 'image_content': '', }
    response = requests.post(searchUrl, files=multipart, allow_redirects=False)
    fetchUrl = response.headers['Location']
    webbrowser.open(fetchUrl)
```

Does anyone how, if possible, I can refine the search to a specific domain?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51274/google-reverse-image-search-in-a-specific-site - Similar question

Comment: I tried `site:` but it seems to be ignored by google

Comment: That answer is from 2013. When I tested it today it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restrict normal searches to a particular domain by adding `site:domain.com`. So you can use that in a parameter `q` of your POST request:

```
domain = 'wikipedia.org'
multipart = {'encoded_image': (filePath, open(filePath, 'rb')), 'image_content': '', 
    'q': f'site:{domain}' }
```